# Have zsh autocompletion use case-sensitive matches only if I typed uppercase

Tags: zsh

How can I make zsh auto-completion give me case-insensitive matches if I typed lowercase, but case-sensitive ones if I typed uppercase?  For example, if I type "HO<kbd>tab</kbd>" it should offer `HOME` and `HOST`, but if I type "ho<kbd>tab</kbd>" it should offer `HOME`, `HOST`, `host`, `hostinfo`, and `hostname`.

The case-insensitive part is easy (`matcher-list m:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}`), and I found [Have zsh return case-insensitive auto-complete matches, but prefer exact matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226685/have-zsh-return-case-insensitive-auto-complete-matches-but-prefer-exact-matches), but that's not quite what I want — if there are any exact lowercase matches, it will not offer the uppercase ones.  I suspect the answer has to do with a left-anchored matcher, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I originally had in mind was that if the typed string contained any uppercase characters, it should be matched exactly.  I still don't know how to do that.  However, a slightly relaxed form works well enough for my purposes:

1. Lowercase characters should match upper- and lowercase characters.
2. Uppercase characters should only match themselves.

Framed like that, the answer is obvious: Remove my existing fully case-insensitive `matcher-list` style (`m:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}`) and replace it with this:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-z}={A-Z}'
```